# ToggleGroup with a ChangeListener<Toggle> always throws a null value to the oldValue

Tags: javafx, menuitem, changelistener

hope someone can help me. I have `menu`  in `javafx` with 2 `RadioMenuItem` this way:

```
public class SiiController implements Initializable {
 private ToggleGroup companyToggleGroup;
 private RadioMenuItem companyARadio, companyBRadio;
 private MenuBar menuBar;
 private Menu fileMenu,companyMenu;
 private Boolean checked;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
 /*......*/
    companyMenu = new Menu("Companies");
    companyToggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
    companyARadio= new RadioMenuItem("Company A");
    companyARadio.setUserData("companya");
    companyARadio.setToggleGroup(companyToggleGroup);
    companyARadio.setSelected(true);
    companyBRadio= new RadioMenuItem("Company B");
    companyBRadio.setUserData("companyb");
    companyBRadio.setToggleGroup(companyToggleGroup);
    companyMenu.getItems().addAll(companyARadio, companyBRadio);

 companyToggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> observable, Toggle oldValue, Toggle newValue) {

            if(checked){
                //do something
            }else{
                //remains the oldValue selected
                //The next line is just for checking the old value   
                System.out.println("oldValue UserData"+oldValue.getUserData().toString());
            }

        }
    });
}
      menuBar.getMenus().addAll(fileMenu, companyMenu);
}
```

The error is that the listener returns a null value to the `Toggle oldValue`. The exception I get is this one:

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at controller.SiiController$4.changed(SiiController.java:284)
at controller.SiiController$4.changed(SiiController.java:280)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.java:74)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:102)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
at javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup$3.set(ToggleGroup.java:137)
at javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup$3.set(ToggleGroup.java:119)
at javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup.selectToggle(ToggleGroup.java:149)
at javafx.scene.control.RadioMenuItem$2.invalidated(RadioMenuItem.java:195)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:109)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
at javafx.scene.control.RadioMenuItem.setSelected(RadioMenuItem.java:180)
at javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup.setSelected(ToggleGroup.java:166)
at javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup.access$100(ToggleGroup.java:54)
at javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup$3.set(ToggleGroup.java:135)
at javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup$3.set(ToggleGroup.java:119)
at javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup.selectToggle(ToggleGroup.java:149)
at javafx.scene.control.RadioMenuItem$2.invalidated(RadioMenuItem.java:193)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:109)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
at javafx.scene.control.RadioMenuItem.setSelected(RadioMenuItem.java:180)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1401)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

In the end what I'm trying to do is if the `Boolean checked`is false then the previous selection on the `ToggleGroup`remains.
Thanks a lot for you time

Comment: The `selected` property seems to be set to `null` and then set to the new value in an ***other*** change event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this in the listenter:

```
if (oldValue != null) {
    System.out.println("old value: " + oldValue.getUserData());
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried, but It supposes not to be null, keeping in mind I select the `companyARadio`from the begining  `companyARadio.setSelected(true);`

Comment: I know. I think it may be a glitch. I had the same problem when I ran your code.

Comment: Ok. I think you're may be rigth. I'll try a workaround. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This happens with RadioMenuButton, but this works as expected when using RadioButton.  There is a [bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189677) for this.

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
companyToggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {
@Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> observable, Toggle oldValue, Toggle newValue) {

        if(checked){
            //do something
        }else{
            RadioButton rbtn = (RadioButton) companyToggleGroup.getSelectedToggle();
            String value = rbtn.getText();
            System.out.println(value);
        }        
}});
```